# Why does an app install as user instead of root will disappear after logout?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, users

To reproduce, login droplet/ubuntu as root. `addnewuser`.
Then logout, then log in as new user.
Install bun js with this command:

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

then follow its instructions.
After installation. test with:

```
bun -v
```

You will see bun installed successfully.
Log out.

Then log into the user account again. Test again with:

```
bun -v
```

The system will say there is no bun.
So the installed application disappeared when trying to re-login.

And this is not available for the user who installed it. That means although I logged in with the same user account, the app is not there.

Comment: I'd try to see if the program is installed with the `find` or locate` command and check if the directory where it is is in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You install the application from a different account than where you want to use the application. Then, you log in to where you want to use the application and do not see the application.

To me, this suggests that the installation procedure you ran (which I did not check myself) installs a local copy of the executable for the user only.

So this is most likely why the app installed as user instead of root, will disappear after logout. It will still be available to the user that installed it.

Comment: it is not available for the user who installed it. That's the point.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to make it more clear. Instead of saying what the system says, include the actual messages from the terminal: much clearer and more precise.